# powershell incremental lines in csv

Tags: powershell

I have a csv journal file like this:
[image]

and I would like to add incremental line numbering like the below:
[image]

Can anyone suggest the easiest way to do this through PowerShell so that every time a file is generated it will automatically insert a column called LINENUMBER and insert the incremental numbering?

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Import-CSV SomeFile.csv | Select *,LINENUMBER | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Line = 1 } { 
    $_.LineNumber = $Line++
    $_ 
} | Export-CSV SomeFile.csv
```

- Uses `Import-CSV` to load the CSV file as a PowerShell object and then  `Select-Object` to return all of it's properties and add an additional property named 'LINENUMBER'
- Iterates through each line of the CSV, incrementing the new LINENUMBER property with a counter variable named `$Line` (which is set to 1 before it iterates).
- Exports the result as CSV overwriting the original (or you could here redirect it to a new file name).

Note that the new column will be last. You could make it the first column by changing the `Select` part to `Select LINENUMBER,*`. If you want it to sit somewhere in the middle that would be slightly more complicated (and likely involve knowing what headers the input file had in advance).

Comment: @Mark: nice 1 mate